# hantepay payment method implement in ionic

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to implement Wechat Pay and Alipay but I want to implement it with Hantepay.it is 3rd party agency called Hantepay. One benefit is that they actually support Alipay (as popular as Wechat Pay) at the same time. We can process payment through Wechat Pay and Alipay with one API.

This is a link to the detailed description document for referencing: http://139.199.112.175

How I can implement it in an ionic project.

Answer (score 0):

1. first create your sandbox account from here
   https://ezidebit.secure.force.com/online/SandboxRequest
2. from here you will get your secret key for testing
3. then make this form in your ionic app or over server side`

   ```
   <form action="https://payments.handepay.co.uk/devtools/sigtest.php? 
        key=MySecretKey" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="action" value="SALE">
         <input type="hidden" name="type" value="1">
         <input type="hidden" name="currencyCode" value="826">
         <input type="hidden" name="countryCode" value="826">
         <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="2512">
         <input type="hidden" name="transactionUnique" value="55f01b80eda38">
         <input type="hidden" name="orderRef" value="Signature Test">
         <input type="hidden" name="cardNumber" value="4929 4212 3460 0821">
         <input type="hidden" name="cardExpiryDate" value="1213">
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
   ```

then call this form

> your payment will done successfully
> signature key is needed in production mode you have to go here to generate
>
> ---
>
> Production mode
>
> =======
>
> the signature key the url is
> https://payments.handepay.co.uk/devtools/sigtest.php?key=MySecretKey

Comment: Are we talking Hantepay or Handepay here?